# Redefine Class Methods or Class

Tags: php, class, methods, redefine

Is there any way to redefine a class or some of its methods without using typical inheritance? For example:

```
class third_party_library {
    function buggy_function() {
        return 'bad result';
    }
    function other_functions(){
        return 'blah';
    }
}
```

What can I do to replace `buggy_function()`? Obviously this is what I would like to do

```
class third_party_library redefines third_party_library{
    function buggy_function() {
        return 'good result';
    }
    function other_functions(){
        return 'blah';
    }
}
```

This is my exact dilemma: I updated a third party library that breaks my code. I don't want to modify the library directly, as future updates could break the code again. I'm looking for a seamless way to replace the class method.

I've found this [library](http://pecl.php.net/package/classkit) that says it can do it, but I'm wary as it's 4 years old.

EDIT:

I should have clarified that I cannot rename the class from `third_party_library` to `magical_third_party_library` or anything else because of framework limitations.

For my purposes, would it be possible to just add a function to the class? I think you can do this in C# with something called a "partial class."

Comment: PHP does not support that. You can extend the class and re-use it. That is it. Sorry.

Comment: Can you rename the original buggy class? Rename it to buggy_third_party, and exend it yourself, giving your class the original name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's called [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). But, PHP doesn't have native support for it.

Though, as others have also pointed out, the [runkit library](http://docs.php.net/runkit) is available for adding support to the language and is the successor to [classkit](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.classkit.php). And, though it seemed to have been [abandoned](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) by its creator (having stated that it wasn't compatible with PHP 5.2 and later), the project does now appear to have a [new home and maintainer](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit).

I still [can't say I'm a fan](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/137028/3) of its approach. Making modifications by evaluating strings of code has always seemed to me to be potentially hazardous and difficult to debug.

Still, [`runkit_method_redefine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php) appears to be what you're looking for, and an example of its use can be found in [`/tests/runkit_method_redefine.phpt`](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit/blob/master/tests/runkit_method_redefine.phpt) in the repository:

```php
runkit_method_redefine('third_party_library', 'buggy_function', '',
    'return \'good result\''
);
```

Comment: this was accepted as the answer: does that mean that PHP supports it? some more information would be nice.

Comment: @nickf: "I don't believe" is a negation; so the OP means "not supported in PHP". As far as I can tell, **PHP does not support monkey patching**.

Comment: @Piskvor, well yes - I can read, but it was curious that this answer was accepted over the other ones which offered some form of guidance.

Answer (score 14):

runkit seems like a good solution but its not enabled by default and parts of it are still experimental.  So I hacked together a small class which replaces function definitions in a class file.  Example usage:

```
class Patch {

private $_code;

public function __construct($include_file = null) {
    if ( $include_file ) {
        $this->includeCode($include_file);
    }
}

public function setCode($code) {
    $this->_code = $code;
}

public function includeCode($path) {

    $fp = fopen($path,'r');
    $contents = fread($fp, filesize($path));
    $contents = str_replace('<?php','',$contents);
    $contents = str_replace('?>','',$contents);
    fclose($fp);        

    $this->setCode($contents);
}

function redefineFunction($new_function) {

    preg_match('/function (.+)\(/', $new_function, $aryMatches);
    $func_name = trim($aryMatches[1]);

    if ( preg_match('/((private|protected|public) function '.$func_name.'[\w\W\n]+?)(private|protected|public)/s', $this->_code, $aryMatches) ) {

        $search_code = $aryMatches[1];

        $new_code = str_replace($search_code, $new_function."\n\n", $this->_code);

        $this->setCode($new_code);

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}

function getCode() {
    return $this->_code;
}
}
```

Then include the class to be modified and redefine its methods:

```
$objPatch = new Patch('path_to_class_file.php');
$objPatch->redefineFunction("
    protected function foo(\$arg1, \$arg2)
    {   
        return \$arg1+\$arg2;
    }");
```

Then eval the new code:

```
eval($objPatch->getCode());
```

A little crude but it works!

Comment: that's a trip! the eval statement then defines the class with the replaced function? so all I need to do is instantiate the object and run with it?

Comment: Yessir! That's all you need to do.

Comment: @SeanDowney , this almost seems to easy to be true. Does this class work out the box? Did you get expected results @SeanDowney? Would make my life hella easier.

Comment: @JPhilly I tried this approach, but get I get a Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class. Where should I run the eval code?

Comment: You shouldn't have the class be loaded in the first place so you still need to have control over whether to require the class or not (if it's autoloaded then you're in luck if not, that won't work)

Also this class could be improved a lot (regex are missing multiple spaces checks) and it wouldn't work if the class had html parts printed in it's methods or php tags open/closed in the middle of the class

Answer (score 14):

For people that are still looking for this answer.

You should use [extends](http://php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php) in combination with [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

like this:

```
namespace MyCustomName;

class third_party_library extends \third_party_library {
  function buggy_function() {
      return 'good result';
  }
  function other_functions(){
      return 'blah';
  }
}
```

Then to use it do like this:

```
use MyCustomName\third_party_library;

$test = new third_party_library();
$test->buggy_function();
//or static.
third_party_library::other_functions();
```

Comment: that is an interesting solution. the only drawback i see being when you need to change the original class's behavior in the places it is used.

Comment: You saved my project's life :). Thanks for the idea! In my framework i've defined FrameworkFunction\RestrictContent, and I allow the other developers to do CustomFunction\RestrictContent for when they need to overwrite something without touching the core framework code. Then when i use an if(class_exists()) to check if the new namespace has been implemented and to use it, otherwise default back to the framework's class.

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness - monkey patching is available in PHP through [runkit](http://docs.php.net/runkit). For details, see `runkit_method_redefine()`.

Answer (score 9):

How about wrapping it in another class like

```
class Wrapper {
 private $third_party_library;
 function __construct() { $this->third_party_library = new Third_party_library(); }
 function __call($method, $args) {
  return call_user_func_array(array($this->third_party_library, $method), $args);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect for wrapping a major class. you can also pass the original php variable to the constructor and swap it out with $this. (handy for a major class, not so handy for lots of instances)

Comment: I would like to see an example how to use this

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called `extend`:

```
<?php
class sd_third_party_library extends third_party_library
{
    function buggy_function() {
        return 'good result';
    }
    function other_functions(){
        return 'blah';
    }
}
```

I prefixed with "sd". ;-)

Keep in mind that when you extend a class to override methods, the method's signature has to match the original. So for example if the original said `buggy_function($foo, $bar)`, it has to match the parameters in the class extending it.

PHP is pretty verbose about it.

Comment: That would normally work however I cannot change the class name due to how framework i'm using is setup

Comment: Then the answer is, you cannot.

Comment: This does not work when the base class calls one of the functions.

Comment: The OP asked how to do it "without typical inheritance". i.e. he's searching something like Java's Reflection

Answer (score 1):

Zend Studio and PDT (eclipse based ide) have some built in refractoring tools. But there are no built in methods to do this.

Also you wouldn't want to have bad code in your system at all. Since it could be called upon by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the code from the answer by @JPhilly and made it possible to rename a the patched class to avoid errors.

Also, I've changed the regex that identifies the about-to-be-replaced function to fit cases where the replaced function doesn't have any class access modifiers in front of its name

Hope it helps.

```php
class Patch {

    private $_code;

    public function __construct($include_file = null) {
        if ( $include_file ) {
            $this->includeCode($include_file);
        }
    }

    public function setCode($code) {
        $this->_code = $code;
    }

    public function includeCode($path) {

        $fp = fopen($path,'r');
        $contents = fread($fp, filesize($path));
        $contents = str_replace('<?php','',$contents);
        $contents = str_replace('?>','',$contents);
        fclose($fp);        

        $this->setCode($contents);
    }

    function redefineFunction($new_function) {

        preg_match('/function ([^\(]*)\(/', $new_function, $aryMatches);
        $func_name = trim($aryMatches[1]);

        // capture the function with its body and replace it with the new function
        if ( preg_match('/((private|protected|public)?\s?function ' . $func_name .'[\w\W\n]+?)(private|protected|public|function|class)/s', $this->_code, $aryMatches) ) {

            $search_code = $aryMatches[1];

            $new_code = str_replace($search_code, $new_function."\n\n", $this->_code);

            $this->setCode($new_code);

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }
    function renameClass($old_name, $new_name) {

        $new_code = str_replace("class $old_name ", "class $new_name ", $this->_code);

        $this->setCode($new_code);

    }

    function getCode() {
        return $this->_code;
    }
}
```

This is how I've used it to patch a Wordpress plugin:

```php
$objPatch = new Patch(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/a-plugin/code.php');
$objPatch->renameClass("Patched_AClass", "Patched_Patched_AClass"); // just to avoid class redefinition
$objPatch->redefineFunction("
    function default_initialize() {
        echo 'my patched function';
    }");
eval($objPatch->getCode());
$result = new Patched_AClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the library is explicitly creating the bad class and not using a locater or dependency system you are out of luck.  There is no way to override a method on another class unless you subclass.
The solution might be to create a patch file that fixes the library, so you can upgrade the library and re-apply the patch to fix that specific method.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with runkit. http://php.net/runkit

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the library class, with everything the same except the class name. Then override that renamed class.

It's not perfect, but it does improve the visibility of the extending class's changes. If you fetch the library with something like Composer, you'll have to commit the copy to source control and update it when you update the library.

In my case it was an old version of https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php. I modified the library's autoloader to fetch my class file instead. My class file took on the original name and extended a copied version of one of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always have access to the base code in PHP, redefine the main class functions you want to override as follows, this should leave your interfaces intact:

```
class third_party_library {
    public static $buggy_function;
    public static $ranOnce=false;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!self::$ranOnce){
            self::$buggy_function = function(){ return 'bad result'; };
            self::$ranOnce=true;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
    function buggy_function() {
        return self::$buggy_function();
    }        
}
```

You may for some reason use a private variable but then you will only be able to access the function by extending the class or logic inside the class. Similarly it's possible you'd want to have different objects of the same class have different functions. If so, do't use static, but usually you want it to be static so you don't duplicate the memory use for each object made. The 'ranOnce' code just makes sure you only need to initialize it once for the class, not for every `$myObject = new third_party_library()`

Now, later on in your code or another class - whenever the logic hits a point where you need to override the function - simply do as follows:

```
$backup['buggy_function'] = third_party_library::$buggy_function;
third_party_library::$buggy_function = function(){
    //do stuff
    return $great_calculation;
}
.
.
.  //do other stuff that needs the override
.  //when finished, restore the original function
.
third_party_library::$buggy_function=$backup['buggy_function'];
```

As a side note, if you do all your class functions this way and use a string-based key/value store like `public static $functions['function_name'] = function(...){...};` this can be useful for reflection. Not as much in PHP as other languages though because you can already grab the class and function names, but you can save some processing and future users of your class can use overrides in PHP. It is however, one extra level of indirection, so I would avoid using it on primitive classes wherever possible.

Answer (score -1):

There's alway extending the class with a new, proper, method and calling that class instead of the buggy one.

```
class my_better_class Extends some_buggy_class {
    function non_buggy_function() {
        return 'good result';
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the crappy formatting)

Comment: Did you read the question? He was pretty clear about not being able to use this solution.