# Cakephp - Overriding model method from controller

Tags: cakephp

I need to override & add methods in a model invoked by a controller. I don't want to write anything inside Model class file because it's used by other controllers too. Methods are like `pagination()` and `find()`, can I do it from inside a controller?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't name the methods something else?

Comment: sounds to me like a very wild idea... why would one want to add methods to a model object dynamically?

Comment: If you need to use your code in multiple controllers then you should probably be using a component, and rethinking your approach.

Comment: @mark - i have only one controller using model in different implementation, any change in model file will affect others.

Comment: @Ross - I have only one controller for searching funtion.

Comment: @Juhan - Sounds like an option, i can create pagination2() but then will paginationCount2() automatically gets called?

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP behaviors are [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). They add methods to a model, which is what you are looking for.

It sounds like dynamically attaching a behavior to the model would get you the outcome you need.

Looking at `Model::__construct()`, I can see that it calls `$this->Behaviors->init($this->alias, $this->actsAs);`.

You may be able to call it again after the model has been instantiated to attach different behaviors (ie. `$this->MyModel->Behaviors->init('MyModel', array('MyBehavior'));`).

---

In fact, a closer look reveals that `$this->MyModel->Behaviors` is an instance of `BehaviorCollection`. As such, you can use the [attach()](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/behavior-collection#method-BehaviorCollectionattach) method.

Comment: thanks for useful information, here is the link of similar case to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137006/php-redefine-class-methods-or-class being from java background i was confused. Seems like using Another function or behaviors is the way to go.

Comment: deizel - can attach behaviors overwrite the methods or it is good for adding new ones?

Comment: Just tested this locally and I am afraid they are only good for adding methods. If you wish to override methods you should extend the class instead.