# Is there a way to OVERLOAD class in PHP?

Tags: php

I looking for a way to overload main project class by plugin class (ofc not whole class - only few methods like headers parser or sth).
Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean? Do you want to overwrite a few select methods of your main class?

Comment: Extend the class? Can you give a little more context to this question?

Comment: Extending is not a way for me. For example I have "foo" class which have many method, one of them is "parse".
I'm looking for method which give included plugin class file to overload foo::parse() [so when core call foo::parse() plugin method will be executed instead of method from core]

Comment: If your core class is not written in a way that's "pluggable", there's hardly any nice way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the class:

```
class A {
  public function __get($value){
    switch($value){
      case "a1": return 1; break;
      case "a2": return 2; break;
    default: // error handler goes here
      return "number out of range"; // or NULL or anything else
       }
     } // end of method __get
   } // end of class A

class B extends A {
  public function __get($value){
     switch($value){
       case "a1": return 11; break; // we overload value of 1
       case "b3": return 3; break; // we add these new properties
       case "b4": return 4; break;
     default: // check ancestor's properties
       return parent::__get($value);
       }
     } // end of method __get
   } //end of class B
```

Comment: It doesnt resolve my problem - core don't know about "B" class so call "A" class. I'm looking for a method where plugin can overwrite actions executed by core.

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods of overriding methods, e.g. [runkit](http://docs.php.net/runkit). However [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137028/6521) to a related question suggests that these extensions are not regularly maintained.