# Can I create new functions for PHP default classes like javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

In Javascript has the Class named Date and I can created a custom function for it:

```
Date.prototype.day = function (value) {...}
```

Can I create functions like this in PHP default classes like DateTime, without developing new child classes?

Comment: It's a bad idea in JavaScript and you shouldn't try to do it in PHP.

Comment: Why It's a bad idea in javascript?

Comment: See here for a full discussion on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can extend the class and use [import aliases](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

```php
use MyDateTime as DateTime;

class MyDateTime extends \DateTime {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}

$d = new DateTime();
$d->foo();
```

However, imports are *per-file*, so you'd need to add that `use` statement to every file in which you want to do this.

Honestly, it would make more sense to just use your own class without the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you shouldn't.

It's called [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and it can be achieved with php's [runkit library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit7.php), esp. with [runkit7_method_redefine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit7-method-redefine.php). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137028/3290062) to a similar question.

However, I find this approach very dirty. It's always better to make your own class.

```php
class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
  function day() {
    return $this->format('d');
  }
}

$date = new MyDateTime('2020-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";   // 2020-01-01
echo $date->day() . "\n";             // 01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **namespace** in PHP

So you do your logic code like this

```
<?php
namespace AnyName;
Class DateTime{
...
}
```

Then In the script where you want to use the function, you *require()* the class file (**logic code**) and import the namespace by using the **use** keyword

Like this

```
<?php
require ('directory/file/....php');
use AnyName\DateTime;
$variable= new DateTime();
```